# How to recall function's decorators from the decorator itself in python

Tags: python, decorator, rate-limiting

I have a decorator that I use to rate limit api requests, but instead of ignore the requests, I want to retry them after some time wait.

The decorator logic is the following:

```
def rate_limiter(self, func: Callable):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if is_request_allowed():
            LOGGER.info('Request allowed')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            LOGGER.info('Request not allowed')
            # sleep(reasonable_amount_of_time)
            # retry_function_with_decorator()
    return wrapper
```

The "allowed" part of the decorator works fine, but the "retry_function_with_decorator()" from the decorator itself is where I'm stuck with.

I have tried to pass the function object to another function and call it from there but it executes the decorated function directly, not the wrapper.

Is this something possible? I'm missing something? or there is a better approach?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current definition, you could just call `wrapper` recursively.

```
def rate_limiter(self, func: Callable):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if is_request_allowed():
            LOGGER.info('Request allowed')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            LOGGER.info('Request not allowed')
            # sleep(reasonable_amount_of_time)
            return wrapper(*args, **wargs)
    return wrapper
```

However, a simple `while` loop would be better.

```
def rate_limiter(self, func: Callable):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while not is_request_allowed():
            LOGGER.info('Request not allowed')
            # sleep(reasonable_amount_of_time)
        LOGGER.info('Request allowed')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you @chepner. What could be the benefits of using the loop instead of the recursion in this case, I just wanted to avoid the loop because I felt that wasn't a safe approach regarding the rate limit checking.

Answer (score 0):

you just need a plain old while loop instead.

However, the decorated function in there attends by `func`, and you can just pass it around or call it again.

Rearranging your code for correctly retrying stuff:

```
def rate_limiter(self, func: Callable):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, _limit_retries=2, **kwargs):
        counter = 0
        while counter < _limit_retries
            if is_request_allowed():
                LOGGER.info(f'Request allowed at attempt {counter}')
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        
            LOGGER.info(f'Request not allowed at attempt {counter}')
            # sleep(reasonable_amount_of_time)
            counter += 1
            # retry_function_with_decorator()
        LOGGER.warn(f'Request denied after {_limit_retries} attempts.')

    return wrapper
```

This will work for a single worker - keep in mind that for a system that will scale horizontally and have several workers - be them multi-threaded, multi-processed, async, or distributed across hosts (with celery or similar), limit rating have to take that into account.

Comment: Yes, it's a distributed system and the function `is_request_allowed()` takes that into account since it uses Redis to persist the values for the rate limiter